# Add Brackets Across String Containing Alphanumeric Characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, etl

I have some data like:

```
Installation start:Mon Sep 13 2021, 7:30:26 AM
Installation completed:Mon Sep 13 2021, 8:03:13 AM
Result code OK
00000000000N0NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN00NNNNNNNNN00NN0NN00NNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
Result code OK
Device has been successfully installed
Single-device update
Received at:Mon Sep 13 2021, 7:18 AM
Control unit type:secondary_ecus
Control unit identifier:meloncake0.0
Target:meloncake.0
Download start:Mon Sep 13 2021, 7:07:34 AM
Download completed:Mon Sep 13 2021, 7:07:41 AM
Installation start:Mon Sep 13 2021, 7:09:29 AM
Installation completed:Mon Sep 13 2021, 7:18:46 AM
Result code OK
Post flash seq failed | Generate maintainer threads failed | : [9A00NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNDANNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNDDDDAZNNNNNNNNNNNN0NN00NAANN0NNNNNNNNNNNNNN]
Result code OK
Device has been successfully installed
Single-device update
Received at:Mon Sep 13 2021, 6:57 AM
Control unit type:secondary_ecus
Control unit identifier:meloncake.0
Target:meloncake1.0
Download start:Mon Sep 13 2021, 6:37:17 AM
Download completed:Mon Sep 13 2021, 6:37:23 AM
Installation start:Mon Sep 13 2021, 6:37:45 AM
Installation completed:Mon Sep 13 2021, 6:57:32 AM
Result code OK
Post flash seq failed | Generate maintainer threads failed | : [9A00000N000N0NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN]
Result code OK
Device has been successfully installed
Single-device update
Received at:Mon Sep 13 2021, 6:26 AM
Control unit type:secondary_ecus
Control unit identifier:meloncake.0
Target:meloncake.0
Download start:Mon Sep 13 2021, 5:52:55 AM
Download completed:Mon Sep 13 2021, 5:53:02 AM
Installation start:Mon Sep 13 2021, 5:54:01 AM
Installation completed:Mon Sep 13 2021, 6:26:48 AM
Result code OK
00000000000N0NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN00NNNNNNNNN00NN0NN00NNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
Result code OK
Device has been successfully installed
```

I would like to put brackets "[", "]" around strings that are 128 characters long and appear after the **Result code OK** line

It has 128 consecutive characters followed by a new line. What can be the regex to search and put brackets around it so that the output is:

```
Installation start:Mon Sep 13 2021, 7:30:26 AM
Installation completed:Mon Sep 13 2021, 8:03:13 AM
Result code OK
[00000000000N0NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN00NNNNNNNNN00NN0NN00NNNNNNNNNNNNNNN]
Result code OK
Device has been successfully installed
Single-device update
Received at:Mon Sep 13 2021, 7:18 AM
Control unit type:secondary_ecus
Control unit identifier:meloncake0.0
Target:meloncake.0
Download start:Mon Sep 13 2021, 7:07:34 AM
Download completed:Mon Sep 13 2021, 7:07:41 AM
Installation start:Mon Sep 13 2021, 7:09:29 AM
Installation completed:Mon Sep 13 2021, 7:18:46 AM
Result code OK
Post flash seq failed | Generate maintainer threads failed | : [9A00NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNDANNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNDDDDAZNNNNNNNNNNNN0NN00NAANN0NNNNNNNNNNNNNN]
Result code OK
Device has been successfully installed
Single-device update
Received at:Mon Sep 13 2021, 6:57 AM
Control unit type:secondary_ecus
Control unit identifier:meloncake.0
Target:meloncake1.0
Download start:Mon Sep 13 2021, 6:37:17 AM
Download completed:Mon Sep 13 2021, 6:37:23 AM
Installation start:Mon Sep 13 2021, 6:37:45 AM
Installation completed:Mon Sep 13 2021, 6:57:32 AM
Result code OK
Post flash seq failed | Generate maintainer threads failed | : [9A00000N000N0NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN]
Result code OK
Device has been successfully installed
Single-device update
Received at:Mon Sep 13 2021, 6:26 AM
Control unit type:secondary_ecus
Control unit identifier:meloncake.0
Target:meloncake.0
Download start:Mon Sep 13 2021, 5:52:55 AM
Download completed:Mon Sep 13 2021, 5:53:02 AM
Installation start:Mon Sep 13 2021, 5:54:01 AM
Installation completed:Mon Sep 13 2021, 6:26:48 AM
Result code OK
[00000000000N0NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN00NNNNNNNNN00NN0NN00NNNNNNNNNNNNNNN]
Result code OK
Device has been successfully installed
```

Code so far:

```
import re

with open('results.txt') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        m = re.search(r'', line)
```

I am new to regular expression so I want to know how can I search for a string of 128 continuous characters followed by new line and only change those strings in the whole data set.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your search needs to keep some caveats in mind, like the newline code `\n`. I was able to get this search to hit correctly, in addition to using a conditional checking for "Result code OK\n" in the previous line.

```py
re.search(r'(\S{126})\n',line)
```

This searches for any sequence of non-space characters 126 characters long followed by a newline `\n`

Comment: The thing to be careful of is the length of the line. Yours aren't really 128 per se (if you copy-paste one of those strings, it shows 127 characters). You may be getting 128 because you're capturing the new-line character as well. My search above modified for 127 instead of 126 in the braces may still work.

Comment: Thanks! How do I add the brackets to the start and end?

Comment: I did it by looping through the lines using enumerate(line). If the regex registered a hit, I would modify that line using the index from enumerate.

Comment: Can you provide that code as well? I tried to use list.insert('[') but it's not giving me the output right :(

Comment: This regex is not entirely correct as it will also select the string with the brackets and take the last 127 characters from it up until  ]\n